# Excel copy range to keep hidden rows

Tags: vba, excel

As the question states, is their anyway to copy/paste a range and copy the hidden rows too?

Currently I use

```
xlWB.Sheets("Template").Range(Template_RFull_Inc).Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Test_Name).Range("A11")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

Is their a code like

```
.PasteSpecial xlHiddenRows
```

If this is too long winded or going to cause a headache I do have a work around

Comment: I don't think there is such an option unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge you can only show them - copy them - then hide them again in a loop.

Comment: Do you mean you want the rows in the pasted sheet to also get hidden?

Comment: Yes, in the source sheet there are 30~ hidden rows and I would like the destination sheet to have the same hidden rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same lines to be hidden in the copy (Test_Name), you have to run something else after the copy. Something closed to that should work.

```
Dim TopRowOriginal As Long
Dim TopRowCopy As Long
TopRowOriginal = Template_RFull_Inc.Row
TopRowCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Test_Name).Range("A11").Row
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range(Template_RFull_Inc).Rows
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Test_Name).Rows(r.Row + TopRowCopy - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = r.EntireRow.Hidden
Next r
```

Comment: I had to modify the above a bit to fit my scenario but otherwise great idea

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by using **.Paste** rather than **.PasteSpecial.**  This is directly from the Macro Recorder:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("1:3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows("1:3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

NOTE:

We Selected the entire row rather than all the cells within those rows.